# How to get current flavor name in gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to know the current flavor in a gradle task:

```
task getAssets(type: Copy) {

   //...

   def currentFlavor = getCurrentFlavor();

   // ...
}

def getCurrentFlavor() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    Pattern pattern

    if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

    if (matcher.find()) {
        projectName = matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    } else {
        println "NO MATCH FOUND"
    }
}
```

But it does not work because `gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()` returns

> [DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[],projectPath='null'}]

Comment: I use this variable to rename the apk file, perhaps this can help:  variant.buildType.name

Comment: this only returns the current flavor when you build the project, not when you sync it.

Answer (score 0):

Add product flavor in Gradle like this

```
 flavorDimensions "environment"
productFlavors {
    staging {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "com.***.***"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "environment"

        applicationId "io.**.**"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
}
```

and now you can get flavor like this

```
BuildConfig.FLAVOR
```

In gradle

```
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def flavor = variant.name
        def versionName = variant.versionName
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to get the flavor in a gradle task, not in Java code

Comment: Try this 


applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def flavor = variant.name
            def versionName = variant.versionName
        }
    }

Comment: this returns every flavor instead of the current one.